# How to get Heroku Logs to show relevant information about error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer, sendgrid

My Rails application on Heroku shows me this error screen:

[image: Rails error screenshot]

When I run `heroku logs` from my terminal it only shows:

```
2016-03-03T22:30:11.442364+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/posts" host=www.mysite.com request_id=9b490b19-ca40-45b9-b09f-16a5b064d174 fwd="23.248.115.183" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=2271ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

How can I get the logs to show some actual information about the error (as they would in the development environment).

This error appeared after and update involving a mailer and sendgrid smtp.

Answer (score 0):

If you have complete control over the Heroku setup then I can recommend hooking up the Rollbar Add-on to keep track of all your errors and their tracebacks. There is a free tier so you can try it first.

https://elements.heroku.com/addons/rollbar

Answer (score 0):

You can tail the logs with:

```
heroku logs -t
```

If you have multiple apps from that directory:

```
heroku logs -t --app the-name-of-your-app
```

Those will give you tailings logs.

Here's Heroku's article on logging (with anchor to --tail):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#real-time-tail